# How to change UIBarButtonItem tint color based on whether UINavigationBar is showing large or normal (collapesed)?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiappearance

Setting the appearance of a `UINavigationBar` title, background, etc. based on whether it is showing large or normal is no problem. But how to update the appearance / tint color of the bar button items accordingly?

Have a code at the following appearance and the code that I used to create it:

[image]

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyCiewController.self]).tintColor = .orange

let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = .orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
appearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterialDark)
        
// Set different title colors for large and normal mode
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: .white]
appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: .black]

// No effect
appearance.buttonAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: .white]
        
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MyCiewController.self]).standardAppearance = appearance
```

So, setting different colors for large and normal title is no problem. However, I did not find any appearance property to do the same for the bar button items. My best guess was to use `buttonAppearance` but this had no effect.

How to make the "Done" button white in the normal nav bar? Is it possible to use appearances to solve this?

Comment: Having similar problems with setting the color of the image, the only thing that seems to work is setting the `.tintColor` property on the item itself